# Maven rpm plugin tries to run installation script on build

Tags: java, maven, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I am trying to create an RPM package to install a piece of software however whenever I try to build it using the rpm plugin it will run the install script while building which will fail since my machine is not the intended target (nor should it be)

The setup is this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <group>Applications/Software</group>
        <mappings>
            <mapping>
                <directory>/tmp/${project.artifactId}</directory>
                <filemode>755</filemode>
                <username>user</username>
                <groupname>group</groupname>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <location>src/main/resources/</location>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </mapping>
        </mappings>
        <requires>
            <require>unzip</require>
        </requires>
        <preinstallScriptlet>
            <scriptFile>src/main/scripts/preinstall.sh</scriptFile>
            <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
        </preinstallScriptlet>
        <installScriptlet>
            <scriptFile>src/main/scripts/install.sh</scriptFile>
            <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
        </installScriptlet>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have also configured the pom packaging to be rpm and I am running "mvn clean package" to generate the rpm.
This is just a builder project meaning that all it is meant to do is to package all files within src/main/resources in the rpm together with scriptlets which will execute when that rpm is run on some target machine.

Am I missing something?

I am building the rpm on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with rpmbuild installed

Comment: I have the same issue.. the install script is run during build, but not on installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just read the RPM documentation and found out that this is totally correct. The install scriptlet is called when the RPM is build, what you probably need is a preinstall or postinstall scriptlet. The installation itself (copying the files) is done by RPM.

Reference: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html

Comment: Yeah I noticed it myself as well. Weird process but got around it. Thanks